# Selenium : driver.maximizeWindow gives selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unexpected command response

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I was trying to crawl through a website `https://www.techwithtim.net/` but while maximizing my chrome window I am getting `WebDriverException`

Here is what I have tried

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\hpoddar\Desktop\Tools\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
s = Service(chrome_path)
url = 'https://www.techwithtim.net/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
driver.maximize_window() # Error on this line
search=driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="search-field")
```

this gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#46>", line 5, in <module>
    driver.maximize_window()
  File "C:\Users\hpoddar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 990, in maximize_window
    self.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\hpoddar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 430, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\hpoddar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unexpected command response
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.66)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00B0D953+2414931]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A9F5E1+1963489]
    Ordinal0 [0x0098C6B8+837304]
    Ordinal0 [0x0097EB34+781108]
    Ordinal0 [0x0097E06A+778346]
    Ordinal0 [0x0097D646+775750]
    Ordinal0 [0x0097C565+771429]
    Ordinal0 [0x0097CB68+772968]
    Ordinal0 [0x0097CAF8+772856]
    Ordinal0 [0x00982D5A+798042]
    Ordinal0 [0x0097DD3B+777531]
    Ordinal0 [0x0097E265+778853]
    Ordinal0 [0x0097E04F+778319]
    Ordinal0 [0x0097D646+775750]
    Ordinal0 [0x0097C565+771429]
    Ordinal0 [0x0097CB68+772968]
    Ordinal0 [0x0097CAF8+772856]
    Ordinal0 [0x00982D5A+798042]
    Ordinal0 [0x0097DD3B+777531]
    Ordinal0 [0x0097E265+778853]
    Ordinal0 [0x0097E04F+778319]
    Ordinal0 [0x0097D646+775750]
    Ordinal0 [0x0097CEBC+773820]
    Ordinal0 [0x0097CD59+773465]
    Ordinal0 [0x0098DA70+842352]
    Ordinal0 [0x009E40DB+1196251]
    Ordinal0 [0x009D42B6+1131190]
    Ordinal0 [0x009AE860+976992]
    Ordinal0 [0x009AF756+980822]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D7CC62+2510274]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D6F760+2455744]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00B9EABA+551962]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00B9D916+547446]
    Ordinal0 [0x00AA5F3B+1990459]
    Ordinal0 [0x00AAA898+2009240]
    Ordinal0 [0x00AAA985+2009477]
    Ordinal0 [0x00AB3AD1+2046673]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75EB6739+25]
    RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x778C8FEF+1215]
    RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x778C8FBD+1165]
```

I am not sure what this error is and why am I getting this error.

**Selenium and ChromeDriver version** :

[image]

Comment: Do the chromedriver and the chrome version match? The code works fine for me.

Comment: @dosas seems like version mismatch was the error